# Construct Polytopes from Arbitrary Edge Sets

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, tropical-geometry

I was wondering if given an arbitrary set of edges in 3-space, if there is a way to determine if those edges can be used to construct a single polytope (allowing for the scaling of edge lengths). In $\mathbb{R}^2$, this problem can be solved with linear programming, but I cannot really find literature for higher dimensions.

I am asking this question since it could have applications in the rational factorization of tropical polynomials.

Comment: Can you clarify how you plan to use the edges to construct the polytope, allowing for scaling the edge lengths? Do you mean that you are given a collection of affine lines $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and you want to know if there is a convex polytope $P$ such that the set $E$ of affine lines generated by the edges of $P$,  i.e. $E = \{ AffineSpan(e) : e \in Edges(P) \}$, is equal to $L$?

Comment: For convex 3-polytope, there is the [Steinitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz's_theorem). For general 3-polytope, it is an open problem ( We don't even know which complete graphs are graphs of non-convex polyhedra).